# How can I access the Knowledge Trending Articles via REST API

Tags: api, knowledge

My first question here so go easy on me pse ;-)

I am using a REST API to get my Knowledge Articles from Saleslorce into my webpage

I want to be able to also show the 'Trending Articles' as they appear in the Digital Experiences site. (see screenshot)

How can I do this please? Any suggestions or help please?
Thanks
Mark

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a Custom LWC or AURA to create a component and place it on whichever page you would like ? And were you able to retrieve Knowledge Article ?

Comment: Have you tried `/connect/communities/communityId/trending-articles` as mentioned in [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_communities_trending_articles.htm)